# Edit Text is set to wrap_content but the graphical layout is showing it as fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a login page where i am having a logo on the top and the username and password edit fields but they show up in the  the emulator as if it's property is set to fill parent.

Please suggest me the solution for this..

Comment: Please add some code. Please.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you add screenshot and layout xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Fix the width of your EditText like this :

```
android:layout_width="250px"
```